# onClick returns SyntheticBaseEvent

Tags: reactjs

i have this code

```
toggleActive (newDate) {
    this.props.changeData(this.state.dateType, newDate)
}

{this.state.list.map((element, index) => {
      return <div onClick={() => { this.toggleActive() }} className="list-item text-truncate text-center" key={`${element}.${index}`} onClick={() => { this.toggleActive(element) }}>{element}</div>
})}

this.state.list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, .. ]
```

but the **onclick** with **this.toggleActive** returns a SyntheticBaseEvent while i need the element variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be passing the event in your toggleAction() function. Something like this.

```
{this.state.list.map((element, index) => {
  return <div onClick={(e) => { this.toggleActive(e) }} className="list-item text-truncate text-center" key={`${element}.${index}`} onClick={() => { this.toggleActive(element) }}>{element}</div>
})};
```

e.target.value should be the value you're looking for.